# Подскажите

Tags: php

Помогите сделать код php
У меня на сайте выводится из базы цифры
Вот строчка

```
'.$row['test'].'
```

Как её доработать, допустим из базы выводится цифра 1, это обозначает "тест1", а если 2 то "тест2"

Comment: Хорошо, у меня есть таблица в базе данных называется ghk, в ней строка test, в эту строку всегда заносится только 1 или 2 цифрами, у меня на сайте данный код  '.$row['test'].' выводит всегда цифры, но мне надо что бы выводил слова, допустим если в базе данных стоит 1, он мне на сайте не должен показать цифру 1 а текст "тест1" а если в базе данных стоит 2 то он должен показать "тест2" типа того,
1 => 'тест1', 2 => 'тест2'

Answer (score 1):

```
$list=array('1'=>'тест1', '2'=>'тест2');

echo $list[$row['test']];
```

а вообще по хорошему - если там много разных вариантов - то делайте таблицу  в БД где и описывайте словесно цифры - а при запросе добавте соединение на таблицу и все

Answer (score 0):

Сравнение в PHP:

```
if ((int)$row['test'] === 0) {
    // здесь у нас идет то, что должно быть выведено, если в $row['test'] лежит ноль или (sic!) что-то, что превратится в ноль при преобразовании в целое
    // например:
    echo 'в переменной записан ноль, вы мужчина';
}
else if ((int)$row['test'] === 1) {
    // если в $row['test'] валяется единица
    // например:
    echo 'ура! вы - женщина!';
}
else {
    // если в $row['test'] оказалось что-то неожиданное
    // например:
    echo 'превед, репликант!';
}
```

Comment: Как вам сказать, мне нужно если показывается цифра 1 он пишет тест1 а если цифра 2 то тест2, 1 => 'тест1', 2 => 'тест2', у меня в базе может в строке test быть 1 или 2, это типа как, если стоит 1 то показывается вы не оплатили а если стоит 2 то вы оплатили

Comment: Кажется, понял, вам нужно сравнение. Обновил ответ.

Comment: А как то уменьшить код можно ?!, что бы он был в 1 строчку
У меня просто вот как показывает
<tr><td><i class="icon-star"></i> Тест:</td><td><strong>'.$row['test'].'</strong></td></tr>

Comment: уменьшение кода - это в моем ответе

Comment: да, echo ((int)$row['test']===0)?'вариант 1':'вариант 2';

Comment: Что то я не понял как именно вписывать заместо '.$row['test'].'

Comment: <strong>'.((int)$row['test']===0)?'вариант 1':'вариант 2'.'</strong>

Comment: У меня что то не работает

Comment: @svoloch196, тогда делайте как @Ale_x предложил: записывайте "по-красивому" в переменную до выведения HTML, в самом HTML просто выводите саму переменну.